# is there a filesystem that a same filepath diverted to different file when different users access it?

Tags: filesystems

I want to access different file when different users access the same filepath.
for example there is a file path "/path/a.txt" in linux, if user1 access /path/a.txt is actually accesses /user1/a.txt, if user2 access /path/a.txt is actually accesses /user2/a.txt

```
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !
```

Comment: if you are using linux, and depending on your specific application maybe you could look at ~ which will be expanded by the shell to the users home directory? so if user1 has a home directory `/home/user1` then `~/a.txt` would point to `/home/user1/a.txt`

Comment: Try searching the [Unix & Linux stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), they may already have something on this (and I think this may be borderline off-topic here).